# Application of Banach fixed theorem for differential equations

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, banach-spaces

> Let $f \in C([0,1] \times \mathbb{R})$ and there exists $0 \leq \gamma 
> < 8$ such that for any $0 \leq x \leq 1, u,v \in \mathbb{R}$,
>     $$|f(x,u)-f(x,v)| \leq \gamma|u-v|.$$
>   Let $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ be constants, then the differential 
>     equations
>   $$\left\{\begin{aligned} &-u''(x)=f(x,u(x)), \quad 0<x<1, \\
>   &u(0)=\alpha, \; u(1)=\beta \end{aligned}\right.$$ 
>   has a unqiue solution $u \in C[0,1] \cap C^2(0,1)$.

The proof can be divided into three parts:

1. If $u \in C[0,1] \cap C^2(0,1)$ is the solution to the differential equations, then $u \in C^2[0,1]$.
2. If $u \in C[0,1] \cap C^2(0,1)$ is the solution to the differential equations, then $u$ satisfies the integral equation
   $$u(x)=\alpha(1-x)+\beta x+\int_0^1 G(x,\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1,$$
   where $G \in C([0,1] \times [0,1])$ is defined as
   $$G(x,\xi):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
   \xi(1-x), &0 \leq \xi \leq x \leq 1, \\
   x(1-\xi), &0 \leq x<\xi \leq 1.
   \end{array}\right.$$
   Conversely, if $u \in C[0,1]$ is the solution to the integral equation above, then $u \in C^2[0,1]$, and $u$ is the solution to the differential equations.
3. Let the metric on $C[0,1]$ be sup-metric, and define $F:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ as
   $$F(u)(x)=\alpha(1-x)+\beta x+\int_0^1 G(x,\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi,$$
   then $F$ is a contraction.

**Proof:**

1. $u''(x)=-f(x,u(x)) \in C[0,1] \Rightarrow u \in C^2[0,1]$.
2. Let $u \in C^2[0,1]$ be the solution to the differential equations. Then, by integrating,
   $$u'(x)-u'(0)=-\int_0^x f(\xi,u(\xi)) \mathrm{d}\xi.$$
   Integrating again, we obtain
   $$\begin{aligned}
   u(x)-u(0)-xu'(0) &= -\int_0^x \mathrm{d}\eta \int_0^{\eta}f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi \\
   &= -\int_0^x \mathrm{d}\xi \int_{\eta}^{x} f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\eta \\
   &= -\int_0^x (x-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi.
   \end{aligned}$$
   Setting $x=1$ and using $u(0)=\alpha,u(1)=\beta$, we find
   $$\beta-\alpha-u'(0)=-\int_0^1(1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi \Rightarrow u'(0)=\beta-\alpha+\int_0^1(1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi.$$
   Substituting $u'(0)$, we get finally
   $$\begin{aligned}
   u(x) &= \alpha+x\left[\beta-\alpha+\int_0^1(1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi\right]-\int_0^x(x-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi \\
   &= \alpha(1-x)+\beta x+\left[\int_0^x x(1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi+\int_x^1 x(1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi\right]-\int_0^x(x-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi \\
   &= \alpha(1-x)+\beta x+\int_x^1 x(1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi+\int_0^x \xi(1-x)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi \\
   &= \alpha(1-x)+\beta x+\int_0^1 G(x,\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi,
   \end{aligned}$$
   i.e. $u$ is the solution to the integral equation
   $$u(x)=\alpha(1-x)+\beta x+\int_0^1 G(x,\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1$$
   Conversely, if $u \in C[0,1]$ is the solution to the integral equation, then
   $$u(x)=\alpha(1-x)+\beta x+(1-x)\int_0^x \xi f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi+x\int_x^1 (1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi,$$
   and so
   $$\begin{aligned}
   u'(x) &= -\alpha+\beta-\int_0^x \xi f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi+(1-x)xf(x,u(x)) \\
   &\quad +\int_x^1 (1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi-x(1-x)f(x,u(x)) \\
   &= -\alpha+\beta-\int_0^x \xi f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi+\int_x^1 (1-\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi.
   \end{aligned}$$
   Differentiating again, we get
   $$u''(x)=-xf(x,u(x))-(1-x)f(x,u(x))=-f(x,u(x)) \in C[0,1]$$
   so $u \in C^2[0,1]$. And since $u(0)=\alpha,u(1)=\beta$, then $u$ is the solution to the differential equations.
3. Let $\rho$ be the sup-metric on $C[0,1]$, and $(C[0,1],\rho)$ be the corresponding Banach space. Then
   $$\begin{aligned}
   \rho(F(u),F(v)) &= \sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1}\left|\int_0^1 G(x,\xi)f(\xi,u(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi-\int_0^1 G(x,\xi)f(\xi,v(\xi))\mathrm{d}\xi\right| \\
   &\leq \sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1}\left|\int_0^1 G(x,\xi) \mathrm{d}\xi\right|\sup_{0 \leq y \leq 1}|f(y,u(y))-f(y,v(y))| \\
   &\leq \frac{1}{8}\gamma \sup_{0 \leq y \leq 1}|u(y)-v(y)| = \frac{1}{8}\gamma\rho(u,v),
   \end{aligned}$$
   where $\frac{1}{8}\gamma \in [0,1)$. Therefore $F$ is a contraction and has a unique fixed point $u \in C[0,1]$ such that $F(u)=u$ by the Banach fixed point theorem. By the second part we can conclude that the differential equations has a unique solution $u \in C[0,1] \cap C^2(0,1)$.

Comment: Have you heard about reduction to a system of first order?

Comment: @Thomas Yes I have learned about that...

Comment: there are two reasons why I'm asking this. The first one is your task 1). If you want to prove this, you first have to tackle the first derivative. To this end you will need an equation for $u^\prime$, which you will get by reduction to a system of first order. Once you have an equation for all derivatives, the magic tool you have to proof continuity of the derivatives up to the boundary is the mean value theorem. Then I wonder whether the sketch of proof in three steps is what you have been asked to do, or whether you have just learned the theorem for the first oder case and are now asked to

Comment: (ctd) give a proof for the second order case. The higher order case is usually treated by applying the theorem for the first order case to the reduced higher order system. I may have overlooked some fine point in your specific setup, though.